# Can I see a file attribute using PEview or Hex view(editor)?

Tags: attributes, hex-editors

When I look inside to a file using PEview, I wonder that where is the file attribute?
On Windows, I can see a file attribute by right mouse click on a file.
if so, Can I see a file attribute using PEview or Hex view? Or, is there any other tool to see file attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) from the Command Line or by running it in a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx):

```
ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D] [/L]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.   
  R   Read-only file attribute.   
  A   Archive file attribute.   
  S   System file attribute.   
  H   Hidden file attribute.   
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.   [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.   
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.   
  /D  Processes folders as well.   
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link
```

Comment: thanks, but I just wonder that Can I read something that "type of file", "opens with", "Created" or "Modified"(and so on) in a file attribute using Hex view(or editor).

Comment: @Dennis The file attributes you are looking for are not part of the file itself but part of the File Directory. The file "opens with" information is part of the registry. A simple hex editor will not have access to this information as part of the file.

Comment: I got it. These attributes are not belong to a file. right? Thank you :)